how to clear this error?
EXP-00019: failed to process parameters, type 'EXP HELP=Y' for help
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
Error: Failed to create dump file. Exit code: 1
Backup operation completed. Closing the application.


... failed to process parameters ...

One of the parameters you gave to the exp command is invalid.

... Error: Failed to create dump file ...

You might guess that there's something wrong with [the location of] the dump file you're trying to create, but that's not necessarily the case.
Show us the entire exp command that you are trying to use.
Also, why are you [still] using exp?
"Oracle Data Pump" (expdp & impdp) have been the Tools of Choice since about Oracle 10g.

To be fair, the datapump utilities can only write to the database server or a shared filesystem available to it, which makes them entirely useless in my experience. Unfortunately as the legacy exp/imp utilities don't support any database features added since the 10g era, those are largely useless as well.
